# Dictionary from DataFrame: key from one column, values from multiple rows and columns excluding NaN

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary

I want to create dictionary from `pd.DataFrame` where I want `id` to be key and all `value_x` are values but excluding `NaN`

Dataframe `newdf`:

```
     id    name  value_1  value_2  value_3
0    ant   jay   10.2     3.5      4.7
1    ant   ann   5.7      10.2     NaN
2    bee   will  7.4      NaN      NaN
3    bee   dave  12.4     1.3      6.9
4    bee   ed    0.8      NaN      NaN
5    cat   kit   NaN      NaN      5.2
```

The expected outcome (value is sorted row by row) is

```
{ant:(10.2,3.5,4.7,5.7,10.2), bee:(7.4,12.4,1.3,6.9,0.8), cat:(5.2)}
```

I am trying to use `.to_dict()` but it does work yet

```
newdf.groupby('id').apply(newdf.iloc[:,-3:].to_dict())
```

or

```
dict(zip(newdf.id, newdf.iloc[:,-3:]))
```

Comment: Are there memory issues stopping you from creating a DF without the values you don't want?

Comment: @roganjosh not so sure I understand your question right but I would say all the errors I got are not related to memory

Comment: What I'm suggesting is creating a DF with the rows that you don't want dropped. If you wanted to preserve the original data too, that might require you having 2 dataframes in memory.

Comment: Make sure you test every answer on your data to figure out which method works best. Just saying, stack is slow on large data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
d = df.set_index('id').iloc[:, -3:].stack().groupby(level=0).apply(tuple).to_dict()
print (d)
{'bee': (7.4, 12.4, 1.3, 6.9, 0.8), 'cat': (5.2,), 'ant': (10.2, 3.5, 4.7, 5.7, 10.2)}
```

Detail:

```
print (df.set_index('id').iloc[:, -3:].stack())

id          
ant  value_1    10.2
     value_2     3.5
     value_3     4.7
     value_1     5.7
     value_2    10.2
bee  value_1     7.4
     value_1    12.4
     value_2     1.3
     value_3     6.9
     value_1     0.8
cat  value_3     5.2
dtype: float64
```

If ordering is necesary and use `pandas 0.21.0` is possible generate `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = (df.set_index('id')
       .iloc[:, -3:]
       .stack()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .apply(tuple)
       .to_dict(into=OrderedDict))
print (d)

OrderedDict([('ant', (10.2, 3.5, 4.7, 5.7, 10.2)), 
             ('bee', (7.4, 12.4, 1.3, 6.9, 0.8)), 
             ('cat', (5.2,))])
```

Comment: Let me ask does`groupby(level=0)` mean grouping by what defined as index the last (the id)?

Comment: I remove `NaN`s by `stack`, so is necesary create index from `id` and then select columns for reshaping, `e.g.` by `iloc`

Comment: I just tried `OrderedDict` and got `TypeError: to_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'into'`. Is this because of Pandas version?

Comment: Yes, it is new functionality in last pandas version `0.21.0` - check second point [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#new-keywords)